# Looking for a software that does edit suggestions and discussions per line

Tags: text-editor, collaboration

I run a team of translators, where we work on text files (similar to txt).
After the translation and editing work is done, each team member looks for mistakes and suggests fixes. The Editor can approve, partially-approve or disapprove each suggested fix. Sometimes there are also discussions on each sentence (each sentence = one line).

Moreover, each team member has their preferences, so I would like them to keep working on their individual platforms/editors for "offline work", and just "upload" their edited file to the system which will keep all the comments and everything on the platform itself.

I'm having trouble finding a software that enables us doing even half of these requirements, starting with "discussion on each line of the file".

Here's a short list of what I'm looking for in this solution:

1. Keep versions of the files.
2. Allow people to "suggest edits". Each line = one change (different from git, for example, where each commit can contain many changes but for the git system is just one change)
3. Allow the Editor to approve/disapprove/approve with changes any edit suggest.
4. Allow having conversation on each of the lines of the file.
5. Goes without saying but keeping all the comments and discussions for future reference.
6. Does not necessarily have to be an online tool.
7. Does not necessarily have to have a real-time collaboration feature.

I know it's quite a lot of requirements, and we're also looking for an option of finding a "half baked" open source platform for which we will add our own features.

Edit: 
Just for a clarification, Google Docs / Microsoft Word may have almost all those features we're looking for, but they don't work well with text files, and we simply can't use any other format.

Comment: AFAIR [PoEdit](https://poedit.net/) offers something similar. It's using GetText, which in its source is a plain-text format – and quite popular. Should be worth a look. Even has dedicated WordPress support :) The site holds versions for OSX and Windows, but I'm sure it's also available on Linux (for Debian and derivatives directly from the repos; I've used it on Ubuntu some years ago).

Comment: I've downloaded and tried PoEdit as you suggested, but was unable to use it on any file other than PO files. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Probably not, as it's intended to work on those PO files only. My thought was using that format for editing, and afterwards convert it to whatever you wish to use when necessary (or, alternatively, switch to that format if possible).